# Redirection message after the form is submitted

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a customized webform; after user submission there will be a dynamic ticket number shown in the confirmation message. If I want to show purely a customized message, how do I do this?

I've tried to create a dynamic link to a page that displays that message, but when I try to refresh the page, that just disappears.

For example: user filled the form -> show a message -> show the dynamic ticket ID.